# what should I flag this question as?

Tags: discussion

I flagged this question as spam but it was declined and wanted to know what was the correct way to flag this question? It was already flagged as low quality so I can't flag this.

I can hardly see this being a legitimate question. 
[Strongloop(connectors:mssql licensing missing or invalid) [on hold]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132507/strongloopconnectorsmssql-licensing-missing-or-invalid)

Comment: It's a copy-pasted error message; it's definitely not spam. Not sure flagging is really necessary, downvotes and closevotes will take care of this one (but it would probably be appropriate to flag as very low quality)

Comment: thanks @Pekka웃, I just thought because of the contact "email address" it was promoting something

Comment: Just google "strongloop" and it is easy to see that it is a legitimate business that has a reason to help their users find solutions in their error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone has pasted a stack trace and given us no context, then it's broken code, but it's missing the code.  Valid close reason for that is:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.